# Do native english speakers pronounce "breadth" differently?

Tags: ipa

Looking up this word breadth in differentl dictionaries shows different IPA representations.

Some are the same.

Some are different, even opposite.

Collins: (bretθ, US bredθ)
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/breadth

Oxford: BrE /bredθ/ NAmE /bredθ/
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/breadth?q=breadth

Macmillan: UK /bredθ/
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/breadth

Cambridge: UK /bredθ/ /bretθ/ US /bredθ/ /bretθ/
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/breadth

Which one are you familiar with?

Comment: I'm British, and I wouldn't normally articulate either /d/ or /t/ here - *my* /t/ gets reduced to a glottal stop **breəθ**

Comment: Most native speakers pronounce it [bɹɛt̪θ]

Comment: @FumbleFingers I watched BBC Learning Enlgish programme "Pronunciation Live". Does the lady, the host, prounce the word in the same way as you do? At about 25min40sec,  https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=946255692464433

Comment: You'd have to ask a linguist with an oscilloscope. As a native speaker, I find it almost impossible to avoid hearing what other people say as "identical" to what I say myself, unless the specific phonemes are ***wildly*** different. Obviously if native speakers were always consciously aware of the fact that different speakers *often* articulate phonemes differently, we'd be so distracted we'd never be able to understand each other!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your reply is reasonable. Appreciate it. My follow-up question sounded unreasonable. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, your follow-up question isn't "unreasonable". It's just not something I personally could answer, since *for my whole life* it's been advantageous for me not to notice ***irrelevant*** differences between how different people use language. Both my parents had strong (different) regional accents that bore no relation to the *actual* regional accent of the area I grew up in, so not being aware of such differences comes naturally to me. But if someone like linguistics prof John Lawler were to look at this question, I'm sure he could enlighten you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have enlightened people like me. Is the Prof John Lawler who majord math in German? I majored math, too. No wonder I incline to ask that question.

Comment: Nah - the John Lawler ***I'm*** talking about [was on the faculty at Michigan from Fall 1972 thru Spring 2009, for a total of 37 years of professoring](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/), so I kinda doubt he majored in math in *any* language, let alone German!

Comment: I think an awful lot of native speakers don't know what those damned little symbols mean. Maybe the vast majority. I am British, I mainly speak RP, and I clearly enunciate the 'd' in 'breadth' (and 'width' for that matter).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey On the contrary, a lot of native speakers of Traditional Chinese Characters know the phonetic notation for bopomofo(Zhuyin). When a chinese character is read, people can think of its phonetic notation in their mind. What an unexpected difference! After all, I used to be taught IPA of RP by British from BBC.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The LinkedIn looks the same professor. Check it out. https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-lawler-b3b5441/

Comment: I speak mostly RP though my parents were Northumbrian. Unlike @MichaelHarvey - who I gather lives nearby - I say **breəθ** as FumbleFingers does. I _would_ notice if I heard someone clearly enunciated the d's in 'wɪdθ and brɛdθ'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suffix "th" is used to turn an adjective into a noun, with the noun form indicating the presence, or the degree to which the adjective is present. For instance, truth is the quality of being true. Often the addition of the suffix is accompanied by a vowel shift. For instance, "long" becomes "length", "wide" becomes "width" (although "width" written with the same vowel letter as "wide", the "i" in "wide" is long, but it's short in "width"). In the case of "breadth", the root is "broad", and the vowel is shifted to "ea". The addition of "th" leaves a complicated vowel cluster at the end, and it is generally simplified to just "th" unless the speaker is enunciating carefully. The spelling "breadth" is to some extent thus a holdover from the etymology rather than a reflection of pronunciation, and serves the further purpose of distinguishing it from "breath".

If you're asking from a listener's point of view, you definitely should, when hearing /breθ/, take (contingent on context) "breadth" as a possibility as to what they mean. If you're asking from a speaker's point of view, /breθ/ is generally an acceptable pronunciation, and if you're having trouble pronouncing /bredθ/, /breθ/ may be preferable. How understandable it will be will depend on context clues and how well the rest of your English is. If you're concerned about difficulties in it being understood, there are alternatives such as simply saying "how broad it is", or, if the x, y, and z dimensions have been established, using those labels.